# Copying cell data based on a changing date

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, conditional-formatting

I have a Google Sheet "Calorie Diary" where I track my calorie intake each day, along with my calories burned. I also keep track of my net calories in relation to my basal metabolic calories (1,230 per day). So, my net looks something like this.

`=SUM(-E29,F29, 1230)`

Column E: Daily Calorie Intake

Column F: Daily Burned Calories

1,230: basal metabolic calories

I also have some cells that calculate the totals for the last week, 14 days, and 30 days to track my net calories for those timeframes. For example, here's "last week"...

`=SUMIFS(G4:G, D4:D, "<="&TODAY()-1, D4:D, ">="&TODAY()-7)`

My question is: I would like to have cells underneath the net totals for the last week, 14 days, and 30 days that displays the daily net that is about to drop off for each of those ranges. For example, under "Last Week," I want to display the daily net calories that is currently 7 days prior and will be dropping off tomorrow.

I'm a Google Sheets novice, but I was able to figure everything else out for my Calorie Diary save for this one item. Could anyone help me?

I hope my question is clear. If you need clarification, please let me know.

I've tried MATCH, COUNT, VLOOKUP, ARRAYFORMULA, and a few others. One of these might be the solution and I'm just unsure of how to implement it correctly.

Comment: If you're using Google Sheets, you're  not using Excel. They are not the same product, and in many ways are not compatible. Please don't use tags that do not actually apply to your post. Tag spamming is a good way to get your question downvoted or closed.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the tip. This is my first time posting here, so I appreciate the guidance, Ken!

Comment: No problem. :-) Just FYI: You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with demo data maybe and expected output(manually entered) so that it gives a clear picture of what is needed.